# Spacing Issues With Tables And <p> (HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-tables, margins

I've got a site based around tables. Basically, I have a body area and the top of the body sits flush with the bottom of the header nav bar. Whenever I type text into the body, the body shifts down some pixels. Here are the examples:

This is before I type anything out:

[image: This is before I type anything out (if you can see it, I know it's kinda dark)]

This is after I type text in (nevermind the colors on top, it's a fading color bar that changes colors):

[image: This is after I type text in. It shifts down.]

I tried to set all the margins to 0px and the padding etc. I can't seem to figure it out. I running CSS styles with the headers and body etc., I can't seem to figure out what attribute is causing this to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put your code into http://jsfiddle.net, so we can toy around with your example.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you dont use tables to layout websites. Its very bad for accessibility.

Comment: @DominicGreen That's kinda ambiguous. What's your suggestion?

Comment: @motoxer4533 Thanks! I'll do that.

Comment: Sorry the norm in the industry now is to use div based layout and only use tables for data. For more info on the reasons why there is allot off stuff online this is quite a balanced article http://www.mardiros.net/css-layout.html

Comment: Ok cool, I'm actually using divs and tables (a combination of both). I've incorporated CSS, HTML and Javascript into it. I'll read up on the link, I'm sure there's a cleaner way I can do what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted this site to divs as opposed to tables. While I didn't entirely figure out what was wrong with this issue, I've learned that there are a whole host of problems with tables (as opposed to divs) especially when it comes to cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I guess (wildly) table cellpadding and before having an empty td.

Comment: Cellspacing and cellpadding are at 0. There is a background image in the table already so I figured that typing text into it would just put the text over top of the background image that is already there and lined up.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the line-height property of the text? [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)